# Finding the overlap between two dictionary keys and creating a new dictionary from both of the dict values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dictionaries as follows:

```
a = {XX: 1000, YY: 2000}
b = {XX: 'foo', YY: 'bar'}
```

and I would like to match the keys of `a` and `b` to output a dictionary in the form:

```
c = {'foo': 1000, 'bar': 2000}
```

I know I can create a set with just the matched keys:

```
set(a.keys()) & set(b.keys())
```

but this doesn't keep the data relations I want together. I feel like I'm overcomplicating something that has a simple Pythonic way to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using intersection of `dict.keys`:

```
{b[k]: a[k] for k in a.keys() & b.keys()}
```

Output:

```
{'foo': 1000, 'bar': 2000}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, since the keys might not have matches in both `a` and `b` and the order is not aligned, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
a = {"XX": 1000, "YY": 2000}
b = {"XX": 'foo', "YY": 'bar'}

print(dict(zip(b.values(), a.values())))
```

Out:

```
{'foo': 1000, 'bar': 2000}
```

Comment: That's totally dependent on the ***order*** of the dict which might be risky. `b = {"YY": 'bar', "XX": 'foo'}` will give a wrong output